# Trouble understanding obsfucated Perl method

Tags: perl

I'm trying my best to decipher some Perl code and convert it into C# code so I can use it with a larger program.  I've been able to get most of it converted, but am having trouble with the following method:

```
sub dynk {  
    my ($t, $s, $v, $r) = (unpack("b*", $_[0]), unpack("b*", pack("v",$_[1])));  
    $v^=$t=substr($t,$r=$_*$_[($_[1]>>$_-1&1)+2]).substr($t,0,$r)^$s for (1..16);  
    pack("b*", $v);  
}
```

It is called like:

```
$sid = 0;  
$rand = pack("H*", 'feedfacedeadbeef1111222233334444');  
$skey = dynk($rand, $sid, 2, 3) ^ dynk(substr($dbuf, 0, 16), $sid, -1, -4);
```

I understand most of it except for this section:
`$_*$_[($_[1]>>$_-1&1)+2]`

I'm not sure how $_ is being used in that context?  If someone could explain that, I think I can get the rest.

Comment: please add some details about what it is supposed to be doing.

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unpack.html in same site you will find more documentation of other function and method, I know bit of perl but frankly unable to convert it with my knowledge.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`pack` and `unpack` take a pattern, and some data, and transform this data according to the pattern. For example, `pack "H*", "466F6F"` treats the data as a hex string of arbitrary length, and decodes it to the bytes it represents. Here: `Foo`. The `unpack` function does the reverse, and extracts data from a binary representation to a certain format.

The `"b*"` pattern stands produces a bit string – `unpack "b*", "42"` is `"0010110001001100"`.

The `v` represents one little-endian 16-bit integer.

The Perl is rather obfuscated. Here is a rewrite that simplifies some aspects.

```
sub dynk {
  # Extract arguments: A salt, another parameter, and then two ints that determine rotation.
  my ($initial, $sid, $rot_a, $rot_b) = @_;

  # Unpack the initial value to a bitstring
  my $temp = unpack("b*", $initial);
  # Unpack the 16-bit number $sid to a bitstring
  my $sid_bits = unpack("b*", pack("v", $sid));
  my $v;  # an accumulator

  # Loop through the 16 bits of our $sid
  for my $bit_number (1..16) {
    # Pick the $bit_number-th bit from the $sid as an index for the data
    my $bit_value = substr($sid_bits, $bit_number-1, 1);
    # calculate rotation from one data argument
    my $rotation = $bit_number * ( $bit_value ? $rot_b : $rot_a );
    # Rotate the $temp bitstring by $rotation bits
    $temp = substr($temp, $rotation) . substr($temp, 0, $rotation);
    # XOR the $temp with $sid_bits
    $temp = $temp ^ $sid_bits;
    # ... and XOR with the $v accumulator
    $v = $v ^ $temp;
  }

  # Pack the bitstring back to binary data, return.
  return pack("b*", $v);
}
```

This seems to be some sort of encryption or hashing. It mainly jumbles the first argument according to the following ones. <del>The larger `$sid` is, the more extra parameters are used: at least one, at most 16.</del> Each bit is used in turn as an index, thus only two extra parameters are used. The length of the first argument stays constant in this operation, but the output is at least two bytes long.

If one of the extra arguments is zero, no rotation takes place during that loop iteration. Unititializes arguments are considered to be zero.

Comment: You made at least two errors in your deobfuscation attempt. You forgot (1) a bitwise and with 1 (`&1`) of the `@data` index and (2) to set `$temp` to the result of XORing it with `$sid_bits` at the end of the loop.

Comment: @nwellnhof Well spotted. Your explanations helped me understand this, as is reflected in the updated answer.